# Meteor: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am using Meteor 0.5.2 and getting following warning in Chrome for each of images which have their src generated by a template helper:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:3000/images/". domutils.js:126
```

In my template I defined the image like this:

```
<img src="images/{{userOwnerAvatar}}" alt="" width="32" height="32" />
```

I am using a template helper function to pull out the exact image name (e.g. "avatar.jpg") from Mongo. All images are visible and loaded correctly in browser.

When I type in the image name directly into template (hardcode image name) the warning disappears.

e.g.

```
<img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" width="32" height="32" />
```

Why do I keep getting this warning and what can I do about it?

Thanks, Vladimir

Comment: I have concluded that inserting only image file name directly in template is not wise in Meteor for some reason so now my helper function outputs the complete image tag. When my helper function outputs the whole image tag all warnings go away.

Comment: Also when dealing with extended Meteor.user() I had to do a check if e.g. avatar field existed (by using if ('avatar' in Meteor.user())).

It seems Meteor calls my function two times and first time e.g. Meteor.user().avatar returns 'undefined' for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of {{userOwnerAvatar}} is not resolving correctly, which is why your browser is saying that "http://localhost:3000/images/" was interpreted as text/html (note the lack of the actual image filename in that URL). Fix your template helper :-)

Comment: I can see the image correctly in the browser and Inspect element in Chrome shows the image url correctly (<img src="images/avatar.jpg">)

When starting meteor application I can see a "image not found" icon for a split second and then actual image replaces it. It's like my helper function doesn't return the image name before the template is rendered. I am going to further investigate the issue.

Comment: I have concluded that inserting only image file name directly in template is not wise in Meteor for some reason so now my helper function outputs the complete image tag. When my helper function outputs the whole image tag all warnings go away.

Comment: @Rahul how do you specify the mime type in a template helper?

Comment: @AndersVindberg Not sure what you meant, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Rahul In order to avoid the error message in Chrome. Is it because the image url is generated reactivly, then Chrome has an empty url until the content loads!¿ Thx.

Comment: @AndersVindberg Yes, that's probably why. So you want to wrap the img tag with an {{#if ...}} to not put it in the DOM until the URL is available.

Answer (score 4):

Related, though not specifically answering the issue above, I had a similar warning/error message. My CSS was like this:

```
.myClass a{
    background: url(my-image.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Fixed it by changing it into (notice the quotes and the forward slash):

```
.myClass a{
    background: url('/my-image.png.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

I don't know why the quotes and slash matter for Meteor (or Handlebars)...

Answer (score 1):

This is the insecure content warning generated by Chrome, saying that the server is sending wrong or missing `Content-type` in HTTP header.  Sometimes this also happens when loading custom Javascript or CSS, etc.

I have also experienced the same issue. Here, the browser expects `Content-type: image/jpeg`,  but it is interpreted as `text/html`. Because you don't specified the `content-type` in your helper.

These are simply a type warnings that has no impact on running the application.

Comment: My helper function only return the image file name - the image is not kept in db but on file system in /images/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, as was able to resolve it by moving my img folder into the public folder of the Meteor project so it was served directly. My source url is still `src="img/pic.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using the iron router package, although the images were not displaying at all.  My images are in the public/ directory.  They would display properly if I was using the url `http://localhost:3000/tracker`, but my page on path `http://localhost:3000/tracker/item` would not load images properly and gave me the aforementioned error.

I was using the following html:

```
<img src="{{this.itemImage}}" alt="{{this.itemName}}">
```

When I added '/' before `{{this.itemImage}}` like this:

```
<img src="/{{this.itemImage}}" alt="{{this.itemName}}">
```

The image would load properly, and there would be no error.