# Content type of stylesheet in Meteoor

Tags: javascript, css, http, meteor

I am trying to set:

`body{
    background-image: url('/assets/bg.png')
}`

But Im getting this warning:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Is your image placed in `/public/assets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Im getting this **error**:

Thats not an error thats a warning message

did you have that `bg.png` on the  `appNAme/public` ?

in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184379/meteor-resource-interpreted-as-image-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html) @sohel khalifa explain why you get this warning message.

> This is the insecure content warning generated by Chrome, saying that
>   the server is sending wrong or missing Content-type in HTTP header.
>   Sometimes this also happens when loading custom Javascript or CSS,
>   etc.

This is how you app structure should look alike.

```
 appName/public
        appName/public/assets
```

with that just call like this.

```
background-image: url('/assets/bg.png')
```

**note**

Everything in `/public` should start map with `/`

Comment: that's exactly what I had before....`assets` is the same thing as `public` as it is neither `client` nor `server`

Comment: hmm try just calling like `/bg.png` im not sure about this `assets` is the same thing as `public` did you read this from docs? _All files inside a top-level directory called public are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include public/ in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference public/bg.png as <img src='/bg.png' />. This is the best place for favicon.ico, robots.txt, and similar files._

Comment: i tried `public` and `assets`, which both didnt work, but when I did `/bg.png` that did work.  many thanks Ethaan

Comment: @redress thats beacause /assest its the "top-level directory" here so you don't need to map like `/assets/image.png` you only need to start the url with the `/`